# Bug na validação do loop while()?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, while

Estou tentando setar o total de uns valores que capturo no banco de dados SQLite, até ai tudo bem porque os valores passados no meu ArrayAdpter é setado na tela sem maiores problemas.
O problema é quando o loop termina com o cursor retornado null, ele para por ali mesmo e não executa o resto do código como se estivesse preso em um loop infinito, porem acho que não esta porque minha aplicação não trava e continua executando outras funções como clicks, então devido a isso no final do código nas condicionais "if" e "else" simplesmente não são executadas e ai não tenha o valor total setado.

Alguma ideia do porque isso esta acontecendo?

Obs: Já tentei trocar a condicional do loop para "whilhe(x < 0) { x++ }" e funcionou, o problema parece estar no retorno do cursor.

```
cursor.moveToFirst();

        if ( cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {

            while ( cursor != null ) {

                Date dataInicial;
                SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                dataInicial = sdf1.parse(cursor.getString(indiceColunaData));

                if (dataInicial.after(ACS.dataFiltro())) {
                    infocard.add("Numero da nota " + cursor.getString(indiceColunaId) + "\n" +
                            "Comprador: " + cursor.getString(indiceColunaPessoa) + "\n" +
                            "Produto: " + cursor.getString(indiceColunaProduto) + "\n" +
                            "Valor: " + cursor.getString(indiceColunaValor) + "R$\n" +
                            "Data da compra: " + cursor.getString(indiceColunaData) + "\n" +
                            "Data de registro: " + cursor.getString(indiceColunaDataAdd).replaceAll(" ", " as ")
                    );

                    soma += Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(indiceColunaValor));

                }

                cursor.moveToNext();

            }

        }


        cursor.close();
        bancoDados.close();

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        String string = df.format(soma);

        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder(string);

        if ( soma > 0 ) {
            if (string.length() >= 7 && string.length() <= 9) {
                total.setText("Total: " + SB.insert(string.length() - 6, ".").deleteCharAt(string.length() - 2).insert(string.length() - 2, ",") + " R$");
            } else if (string.length() < 4) {
                total.setText("Total: " + SB.insert(string.length() - 3, "0") + " R$");
            } else {
                total.setText("Total: " + SB.deleteCharAt(string.length() - 3).insert(string.length() - 3, ",") + " R$");
            }
        }else {
            total.setText("Total: 0,00 R$");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente percorrer o `Cursor` assim:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select...");
c.moveToFirst();

for(int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++){
    String valor = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Nome da coluna"));
    //Seu código...
    c.moveToNext();

}

c.close();
```

Dessa maneira você deve não ter mais problemas!